# swift update contact fails

Tags: swift, contacts

In my app, I collect data from clients like names, addresses, phone numbers etc. I'd like to offer a button for saving and updating these data to apple's contacts app.

Therefor I wrote this class:

```
class ContactsClass {
    func addToContacts(
        lastName: String,
        firstName: String,
        mail: String = "",
        phone1: String = "",
        street: String,
        city: String,
        postCode: String
    ) {
        // Create a mutable object to add to the contact
        let contact = CNMutableContact()
            
        contact.givenName = firstName
        contact.familyName = lastName
        
        if mail != "" {
            let homeEmail = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: mail as NSString)
            contact.emailAddresses = [homeEmail]
        }
        
        contact.phoneNumbers = []
        if phone1 != "" {
            contact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMain, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone1)))
        }

        let homeAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
        homeAddress.street = street
        homeAddress.city = city
        homeAddress.postalCode = postCode
        contact.postalAddresses = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: homeAddress)]

        // Save the newly created contact
        let store = CNContactStore()
        let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
        saveRequest.add(contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: gruppe)
        do {
            try store.execute(saveRequest)
        } catch {
            print("Saving contact failed, error: \(error)")
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
    
    
    func checkForExistingContact(familyName: String, givenName: String) -> CNContact? {
        let store = CNContactStore()
        do {
            let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: familyName)
            let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
            let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
            for contact in contacts {
                if contact.givenName == givenName {
                    return contact
                }
            }
            return nil
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    
    func updateContact(
        contact: CNContact,
        lastName: String,
        firstName: String,
        mail: String = "",
        phone1: String = "",
        street: String,
        city: String,
        postCode: String
    ) {
            let mutableContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
            
            mutableContact.givenName = firstName
            mutableContact.familyName = lastName
            
            if mail != "" {
                let homeEmail = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: mail as NSString)
                mutableContact.emailAddresses = [homeEmail]
            }
            
            mutableContact.phoneNumbers = []
            if phone1 != "" {
                mutableContact.phoneNumbers.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMain, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone1)))
            }
            
            let homeAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
            homeAddress.street = street
            homeAddress.city = city
            homeAddress.postalCode = postCode
            mutableContact.postalAddresses = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: homeAddress)]
            
            
            // Save the updated created contact
            let store = CNContactStore()
            let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
            saveRequest.update(mutableContact)
            do {
                try store.execute(saveRequest)
            } catch {
                print("Saving contact failed, error: \(error)")
                // Handle the error.
            }
    }
}
```

My button calls this func

```
    private func addToContacts() {
        let con = ContactsClass()
        
        if let contact = con.checkForExistingContact(familyName: klient.nachname!, givenName: klient.vorname!) {
            con.updateContact(
                contact: contact,
                lastName: klient.nachname!,
                firstName: klient.vorname!,
                mail: klient.email ?? "",
                phone1: klient.telefon1 ?? "",
                street: selectedAddress?.strasse ?? "",
                city: selectedAddress?.ort ?? "",
                postCode: selectedAddress?.plz ?? ""
            )
        } else {
            con.addToContacts(
                lastName: klient.nachname!,
                firstName: klient.vorname!,
                mail: klient.email ?? "",
                phone1: klient.telefon1 ?? "",
                street: selectedAddress?.strasse ?? "",
                city: selectedAddress?.ort ?? "",
                postCode: selectedAddress?.plz ?? ""
            )
        }
    }
```

My problem:

- Adding the contact works fine. No problems.
- Updating this contact doesn't.
  Error in log:

```
2023-06-21 21:28:25.166437+0200 justCare 2[64058:433979] [core] Attempted to register account monitor for types client is not authorized to access: {(
    "com.apple.account.CardDAV",
    "com.apple.account.Exchange",
    "com.apple.account.LDAP"
)}
2023-06-21 21:28:25.166546+0200 justCare 2[64058:433979] [accounts] CNAccountCollectionUpdateWatcher 0x6000020a04c0: Store registration failed: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)"
2023-06-21 21:28:25.166605+0200 justCare 2[64058:433979] [accounts] CNAccountCollectionUpdateWatcher 0x6000020a04c0: Update event received, but store registration failed. This event will be handled, but the behavior is undefined.
2023-06-21 21:28:25.340559+0200 justCare 2[64058:433979] [api] Attempt to read notes by an unentitled app
2023-06-21 21:28:25.343112+0200 justCare 2[64058:433979] [General] A property was not requested when contact was fetched.
2023-06-21 21:28:25.348149+0200 justCare 2[64058:433979] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019e1d3154 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019dcf24d4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019e1d2ff8 +[NSException exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:] + 0
    3   Contacts                            0x00000001b16f23c4 -[CNMutableContact setPhoneNumbers:] + 328
    4   justCare 2                          0x0000000100a04e04 $s10justCare_213ContactsClassC13updateContact7contact8lastName05firstI09birthDate4mail6phone16phone26mobile6street4city8postCode6gruppeySo9CNContactC_S2S10Foundation0L0VSgS8StF + 1752
    5   justCare 2                          0x0000000100e3eb64 $s10justCare_220KlientenAdressenViewV13addToContacts33_94E28232C5F5EF34661BF1E9CA92653DLLyyF + 6208
    6   justCare 2                          0x0000000100e3d314 $s10justCare_220KlientenAdressenViewV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI05TupleE0VyAE0E0PAEE5sheet11isPresented9onDismiss7contentQrAE7BindingVySbG_yycSgqd__yctAeHRd__lFQOyAE6HStackVyAGyAE6SpacerV_AE6ButtonVyAiEE10labelStyleyQrqd__AE05LabelU0Rd__lFQOyAE0V0VyAE4TextVAE5ImageVG_AE08IconOnlyvU0VQo_GAiEE8disabledyQrSbFQOyA8__Qo_A10_SgAiEE5alert_AK7actionsQrAE18LocalizedStringKeyV_APqd__yXEtAeHRd__lFQOyA10__AGyAWyA1_G_A16_tGQo_AiEE5frame5width6height9alignmentQr12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVSg_A26_AE9AlignmentVtFQOyAE7DividerV_Qo_AiEE4helpyQrA15_FQOyA10__Qo_tGG_AA014AdresseAddEditE0VQo__AiEE0M6Change2of7performQrqd___yqd__ctSQRd__lFQOyAiEEA19_A20_A21_A22_QrA26__A26_A28_tFQOyAE4ListVyAA0cD0CAE7ForEachVyAE14FetchedResultsVyA45_G10Foundation4UUIDVSgAiEE20listRowSeparatorTint_5edgesQrAE5ColorVSg_AE12VerticalEdgeO3SetVtFQOyAiEE16listRowSeparator_A56_QrAE10VisibilityO_A63_tFQOyAiEE7paddingyQrAE4EdgeOA62_V_A26_tFQOyAiEE3tagyQrqd__SHRd__lFQOyASyAGyAiEEA19_A20_A21_A22_QrA26__A26_A28_tFQOyAE6VStackVyAGyAiEEA19_A20_A21_A22_QrA26__A26_A28_tFQOyA1__Qo_Sg_A74_A74_tGG_Qo__A73_yAGyASyAGyA1__AuiEE15foregroundColoryQrA59_FQOyA3__Qo_A80_SgA3_SgtGG_ASyAGyA1__AUA1_SgA85_tGGtGGtGG_A45_Qo__Qo__Qo__Qo_GG_Qo__AA0C0CQo_tGyXEfU_A34_yXEfU_yycfU8_ + 36
    7   SwiftUI                             0x00000001c6e285e4 block_destroy_helper + 1276
    8   SwiftUI                             0x00000001c6e26978 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 23992
    9   SwiftUI                             0x00000001c6e269dc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 24092
    10  AppKit                              0x00000001a15218a8 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 440
    11  AppKit                              0x00000001a15216c0 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 72
    12  AppKit                              0x00000001a1521604 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 100
    13  AppKit                              0x00000001a152152c -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 204
    14  AppKit                              0x00000001a1521450 -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 88
    15  AppKit                              0x00000001a151ea54 NSControlTrackMouse + 1480
    16  AppKit                              0x00000001a151e460 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 144
    17  AppKit                              0x00000001a151e318 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 488
    18  AppKit                              0x00000001a151d7e4 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 448
    19  AppKit                              0x00000001a151c2cc -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 3476
    20  AppKit                              0x00000001a14a6f08 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 364
    21  AppKit                              0x00000001a14a6bc8 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 284
    22  AppKit                              0x00000001a14a5f0c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1556
    23  AppKit                              0x00000001a16f5fc4 -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] + 60
    24  AppKit                              0x00000001a136d368 -[NSApplication run] + 500
    25  AppKit                              0x00000001a1344794 NSApplicationMain + 880
    26  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c643f6b8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 + 8272
    27  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c75a05ac OUTLINED_FUNCTION_14 + 188
    28  SwiftUI                             0x00000001c6e20c48 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 136
    29  justCare 2                          0x0000000101365e9c $s10justCare_20aB5_2AppV5$mainyyFZ + 40
    30  justCare 2                          0x000000010136619c main + 12
    31  dyld                                0x000000019dd23f28 start + 2236
)
```

Why isn't the contact updated? I would be very thankful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be around modifying the contact's phone number based on the stack trace.

> 3   Contacts                            0x00000001b16f23c4 -[CNMutableContact setPhoneNumbers:] + 328

There's also the message:

> A property was not requested when contact was fetched.

Looking at your code, your `checkForExistingContact` method only fetches the attributes `CNContactGivenNameKey`, `CNContactFamilyNameKey`, and `CNContactEmailAddressesKey`. The phone number key is not listed.

There is also this note in the documentation for [`CNMutableContact`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnmutablecontact):

> You may modify only those properties whose values you fetched from the contacts database. When fetching a contact, you specify which properties you want to retrieve from the database. The contact store then populates the properties of a `CNContact` object with those values. After creating a mutable copy of that object, you can modify only those properties for which a value exists. If you attempt to access a property that is not available, the `CNMutableContact` object throws a `CNContactPropertyNotFetchedExceptionName` exception.

You need to update the line:

```
let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
```

to include all possible keys you will try to update in your `updateContact` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my hero of the day.